# Algorithm to find true value range in bool array

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Is there an algorithm to find a range in sequence which has a large numbers of elements?

I understand that if there are multiple true intervals, it is impossible to find all intervals within O(logn) time complexity.

Even if there is only one true interval, can't you find the interval within O(logn)?

Because the array is long (about 1 billion), a fast algorithm is needed.

```
def fn(idx):
    # In reality, it includes logic that takes 0.5 seconds to determine this index is true or false.
    return 500000000 <= idx <= 700000000


def find_range(fn, a, b):
    ...


assert find_range(fn, 0, 1000000000) == [500000000, 700000000]
```

Comment: After thinking about it a little more, I realized that in the worst case (if only one point is true), no matter what happens, you will have to search N times to find the value, so the answer to your question is "impossible".

Comment: One-dimensional battleship!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't find the interval in O(log). The range could have size 1, and then the challenge is to find a single 1 in an ocean of zeroes. There is no clue about which way to continue a search. In the worst case you'll look at all zeroes before finding the 1, giving a time complexity of O().

If there is knowledge about the minimum size  of the interval, you can iterate the array with steps of , and once you hit a 1, you can use binary search to find the boundaries of the interval. This results in a worst case
time complexity of O(/ + log(min(−, ))).